# find td elements which do not have checkbox with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the td elements in a table which do not have checkboxes with the class name as `chkCheckBox1`

Created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2exqwwbz/1/)

I've tried to use `.filter` and find the `td` but that didn't worked.

```
$("#LstDocTemp").filter("td:not(.chkCheckBox1)")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code is currently looking for `td`s without the class, you need to look for the `input` (since the input is the element with the class) and then get it's parent: `$("#LstDocTemp").find("td input:not(.chkCheckBox1)").parent()`

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:not()` and `:has()` like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2exqwwbz/2/)

```
$("td:not(:has(input.chkCheckBox1:checkbox))")
```

Comment: ...because the OP's attempt was filtering out `td` elements that had the `.chkCheckBox1` class, not ones with *descendants* who did.

Comment: Too much CSS . Any jQuery way ?

Comment: There is no `:has()` in css but i guess this is more jquery way https://jsfiddle.net/2exqwwbz/3/

Answer (score 0):

This also works. Single selector up front to get the input itself, then the containing TD.

```js
$(function(){
var mySelection = $("#LstDocTemp td input:not(.chkCheckBox1)").parent();
   console.log(mySelection)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="LstDocTemp" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="instruction_grid">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" class="ins_sl_no">
                Sl No.
            </th>
            <th align="left" class="selct_column">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelectAll" name="chkSelectAll" />
            </th>
            <th align="left" class="doc_title_1">
                Document title
            </th>
            <th align="left" class="description">
                Description
            </th>
            <th align="center" class="revision">
                Revision
            </th>
            <th align="left" class="part_no">
                Parts name
            </th>
            <th align="center" class="issue_no">
                Issue
            </th>
            <th align="center">
                Link
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox" id="chkbox_" />
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox1" id="chkbox_" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class="dark_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="light_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="icon_add" title="Add">Add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox" id="Checkbox1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox1" id="Checkbox1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class="dark_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="light_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="icon_add" title="Add">Add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox" id="Checkbox2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="chkItem" class="chk chkCheckBox1" id="Checkbox2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Test
            </td>
            <td class="dark_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="light_highlight">
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="icon_add" title="Add">Add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```